# Swig unsigned char* to short[]

Tags: char, byte, swig, unsigned, short

```
 %apply (char* STRING,size_t LENGTH)
 {
         (char* dataBuffer, int size)
 };
```

This is used for convert `char*` to `byte[]`.

But I need to convert `unsigned char*` to `short[]`

```
 %apply (unsigned char* STRING,size_t LENGTH)
 {
        (unsigned char* dataBuffer, int size)
 };
```

This apply isn't working? 
How can I fix it?